# Spark dataset Combine multiple rows

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

This is my dataset,

```
Name Group         Age
A    [123]          10
B.   [123,456]      20
C.   [456,789]      30
D.   [900]          40
E.   [800,900]      50
F.   [1000]         60
```

Now I want to merge `Group` such that, the result looks like

```
 Name       Group                    Age
    A,B,C    [123,456,789]          10,20,30
    D,E      [900,800]              40,50
    F.       [1000]                 60
```

I tried arrays contains but that is not giving me what I want. I tried self join too. Anyone can help with a java solution.

Edit:

I found ReduceFunction which can do something similar.

```
dataset.reduce(new ReduceFunction<Grouped>(){

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 8289076985320745158L;
            @Override
            public Grouped call(final Grouped v1, final Grouped v2) {

            if (!Collections.disjoint(v1.getGroup(), (v2.getGroup()))) 
               {
                    v1.getAge().addAll(v2.getAge());
                    v1.getGroup().addAll(v2.getGroup());
                    v1.getName().addAll(v2.getName());

                }
 }
```

}

But how to do this for all rows???

This is able to give me first 2 rows reduced to :

```
Name   Group         Age
A,B    [123,456]          10,20
```

Comment: easier in scala. is that an option that you can clone from?

Comment: i found a scala solution but I am not able to convert that to java. :(

Comment: I advise skip java with spark

Comment: could you provide the scala solution you have. I can give it a try

Comment: Ok will give it aburl soon

Comment: may be the first data wrangling I cannot solve...rather tough

Comment: sparkwise that is

Comment: ok np.. Thanks for trying

Comment: i will look again but tough

Comment: seems like a graphx problem?

Comment: I could not find a spark scaleable approach.

Comment: So, what is your course of action then?

Comment: @thebluephantom still struggling, i found something called a ReduceFunction in spark .

Comment: can you point me to the scala solution as in my view this is an example of a non-partitonable saprk problem

Comment: I found the solution in stackoverflow last week. Let me search that. Meanwhile i have added some edits to the question and added a recent partial solution i found. Can you look at that and see if helps in any way.